# laravel query orderBy doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all my items from item table ordering by product id, desc or asc.

Query :

```
    public function getAllItems($brandid)
    {
       $data=DB::table('items')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                            ->orderBy('productid' , 'desc')
                            ->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

Data appears with no order by product id, orderBy is not working. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Try to print query and debug for column name and other syntax.

Comment: You have a missing `{` to start the `getAllItems()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved, I had 2 functions with the same name, my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To check your query statement to confirm the problem with your query builder:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$data=DB::table('items')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                       ->orderBy('productid' , 'desc')
                       ->get();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```